# adventureworks_2012_data attach fail in sql express

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

Hi I am trying to attach adventurworks.dmf to sql server express 2012 but I am getting error
The database 'AdventureWorks2012' cannot be opened because it is version 705. This server supports version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

Comment: my mistake I was using sql server 2008 express not  2012  problem was solved when download correct version of adventureworks2008

Answer (score 0):

The adventureworks 2012 not support.so try "adventurework 2008" database.Or update your server version